# How to prevent e.force:createRecord event to navigate record after record created

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

I have a lightning component and in my component i have on button for new record its work fine but after record created it goes to record detail page. I want to prevent navigate event and close the model and show the toas message on the same page.  here is my sample code .

```
<ui:button label="New" class="newbtn right" press="{!c.newEvent}"/>
```

JS-controller

```
 newEvent : function(component, event,helper) {

        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName":  "Event"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();        



    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code work for me..

```
function (component, event, helper) {
        var windowHash = window.location.hash;
        var recordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        recordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Event",
            "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
                window.location.hash = windowHash;
            },
            "navigationLocation":"LOOKUP"
        });
        recordEvent.fire();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is what we call a _code dump_. It's a block of code with no explanation as to how it works. Code dumps tend to make poor answers, and lead to a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" that make it hard for others to apply this to their own problems. The best answers tend to explain things like _what_ the problem is, _how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works. You should [edit] your answer to include more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own custom component. There is no way to stop the navigation for the standard event provided by Salesforce.

Comment: why the downvotes? This is the only possible answer and it's correct in my view.

Comment: @praveen just fyi the above mention solution work perfectly